# Show posts by quarter

Tags: posts, loop

How would I list an author's WordPress posts by quarter in `author.php`?

Current relevant `author.php` code is as follows (post is custom type "press mentions", FYI).

This presents a single list of all this author's posts.
But how do I break this list up in to segments, with quarterly headers, ie. "2015 Q3", "2015 Q4", 2016 Q1", "2016 Q2"?

Quarters are four three-month periods running from January 1.

Posts should appear in same order as present, but segmented by quarter. So, the latest quarterly heading appears at top and so forth.

```
    <!-- Press appearances -->
    <?php
      // Count press appearances
      $post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = '" . $curauth->ID . "' AND post_type = 'pressmention' AND post_status = 'publish'");
    ?>
    <h5><?php echo '<span class="label label-primary">'.$post_count.'</span>'; ?> Media appearances:</h5>
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
      <tbody>
      <?php // Show custom post list - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178739/displaying-custom-post-types-in-author-php
          $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'pressmention' ,
          'author' => get_queried_object_id(), // this will be the author ID on the author page
          'showposts' => 200
      );
      $custom_posts = new WP_Query( $args );



      if ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ): while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : $custom_posts->the_post();?>
      <tr>
        <!-- changed th, removed scope="row", was width="110" and "125" -->
        <td class="col-xs-2"><?php the_time('M d, Y'); ?></td>
        <td class="col-xs-3"><img src="https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,'press_mention_information_publication-url',true); ?>" alt="Publication"> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,'press_mention_information_publication-name',true); ?></td>
        <td class="col-xs-7"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link: <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
          <!-- changed th, removed scope="row" -->
          <tr><td colspan="2">No posts.</td></tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a helper function to map a *month* to a *quarter*:

```
function wpse_get_month2quarter( $month )
{
    return ceil( $month / 3 );
}
```

We could then consider what to do with input values that are not integers in the set `{1, ..., 12}`.

*ps: I got the idea for the formula from this [Excel blog](http://excelunplugged.com/2014/05/19/formula-to-get-quarters-from-dates-in-excel/) by Gašper Kamenšek*

To get the Quarter within the loop we can e.g. use:

```
echo wpse_get_month2quarter( get_the_date( 'n' ) );
```

**Example**

Here's one idea for your loop:

```
if ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : 

    $prev = null;

    while ( $custom_posts->have_posts() ) : 

        $custom_posts->the_post();

        $current = sprintf( 
            '%d Q%d', 
            get_the_date( 'Y' ), 
            wpse_get_month2quarter( get_the_date( 'n' ) )
        );

        if( $prev !== $current )
        {
            printf( '<tr><td colspan="3">%s</td></tr>', $current );
            $prev = $current;
        }

        // ... etc ...
```

where we inject each quarter section once and assume that query is ordered by date.

But there are many ways to implement this.

*If possible you should try to use and modify the main query, via `pre_get_posts`, instead of introducing another secondary query.*

Comment: Let me try to understand this - I’m confused about how to actually use the function and `add_action` in my code…    

I should put your helper function in functions.php, right?    
That works fine.    
  
But, if I add `'wpse_with_quarter_tr_segments' => true,` to the `$args` of my `$custom_posts = new WP_Query( $args );` above, the page throws a 500 error.    
  
And that’s without echoing `echo wpse_get_month2quarter( get_the_date( 'n' ) );` or using your `add_action` example. The page also throws a 500 error then.  
  
Also confused about what to do with the `add_action` example.

Comment: I updated the answer with another example that's a plain PHP approach. I used the hook example to keep it more WordPress relevant. Sorry, there was a typo that should be fixed now. Adding a new input argument shouldn't produce a PHP error. Just tested this on my dev install successfully. @RobertAndrews

Comment: PS: I removed the second example, to avoid possible confusion @RobertAndrews

Comment: Ah-hah, I see. This works now, when I add the helper function and pay closer attention to threading your provided loop code in my loop, before my other loop output. I like it! 
So that I understand what’s happening here…  
We use the function to derive a quarter from the month, prefix the integer with “Q” and then output the combined Q and integer following the Y year, using “prev” and “current” to cycle through incrementally?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. yes that's a good description of what's happening there. ps: I removed an extra `?>` from my example, that must have come when I copied from your code. @RobertAndrews